# Finding a closed formula using Baker-Hausdorff formula for a unitary transformation; An endless commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator

Consider the Baker-Hausdorff formula for two operators $a_1$ and $iHt$:
$$e^{iHt}a_1 e^{-iHt} =a_1+[iHt,a_1]+\frac{1}{2!}[iHt,[iHt,a_1]]+\frac{1}{3!}[iHt,[iHt,[iHt,a_1]]]+....,$$
where $[A,B]=AB-BA$. In the case of my problem, $H=\omega(a_1^\dagger a
_1+a_2^\dagger a
_2)+J(a_1^\dagger a
_2+a_1a_2^\dagger)+\eta a_1^\dagger$. Thus one can write $[iHt,a_1]=\alpha\, a_1+\beta \,a_2+\gamma,$ and  $[iHt,a_2]=\alpha\, a_2+\beta \,a_1,$ where the new parameters are either imaginary $(\alpha, \beta)$ or complex $(\gamma)$.  So, I need to find the following:
$$ a_1\,+(\alpha a_1+\beta a_2+\gamma)+\frac{1}{2!}\Big\{\alpha\Big(\alpha a_1+\beta a_2+\gamma\Big)+\beta\Big(\alpha\, a_2+\beta \,a_1\Big)\Big\}+\frac{1}{3!}\Big\{\alpha\Big(\alpha (\alpha\, a_1+\beta \,a_2+\gamma)+\beta (\alpha\, a_2+\beta \,a_1)+\gamma\Big)+\beta\Big(\alpha\, (\alpha\, a_2+\beta \,a_1)+\beta \,(\alpha\, a_1+\beta \,a_2+\gamma)\Big)\Big\}+....$$

In other words, in each new term, one should replace $a_1$ by $(\alpha\, a_2+\beta \,a_1+\gamma)$ and $a_2$ with $(\alpha\, a_2+\beta \,a_1)$, and repeat this procedure $N$ times, and finally calculate the limit when $N\rightarrow \infty$.

Does anyone know a systematic way to find a closed formula for the answer. The answer is given in equation 6 of [enter link description here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.00075.pdf), and I'm trying to derive it. There might be a better approach there, but it doesn't come to my mind now!

Comment: Are you sure that that hamiltonian is meant to include unbalanced non-hermitian terms? That's unlikely to come up from realistic physical scenarios, but it *is* likely to make your life miserable.

Comment: Quick Hint : Differentiate with 't' (aka equation of motion trick works perfect for any quadratic exponents of canonical operators).

Comment: @Emiliobut Pisanty Yes, $H$ has another term like $-\eta^* a_1$ but since it commutes with $a_1$, I did not write it. By the way, today we Do have non-Hermitian Hamiltonians with real spectra. Google "non-Hermitian quantum mechanics".

Comment: @Sunyam That does not help me. I want to calculate the expression and get a closed formula, as is given in equation 6 of the above reference.

Comment: @Saeid That trick i mentioned is the quickest way to arrive at a closed expression.

Comment: @Sunyam Taking the time derivative gives (after simplification) $e^{iHt} \dot{a_1}e^{-iHt}$, but what is the next step? At this moment, I only need $a_1$ in this particular rotating frame. The equation of motion won't be difficult to obtain afterwards.

Comment: Use commutation relationships and get a linear ODE with source terms and solve it.

Comment: @Sunyam Sorry, but your answer is not clear to me. The commutators are not difficult to find, because each time I get $\text{a coefficient}\times a_1$. But the problem is: how to find the recursion (see the second formula above).

Comment: You don't need to find recurrences, you will get a 1st order ODE of type $\frac{d} {dt} \hat A(t) =M \hat A(t) + B$. Solving it gives what you are after.